# Null Pointer Exception on Primefaces MenuItem outcome attribute

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, navigation

I'm using prime faces 4.0 on a jsf 2.2 web project. I'm using template including the menu bar and footer part of the page.

I created a folder named `user` for accessing the pages under it via an authentication filter redirecting unauthorized requests to a proper page.

but the links on the menu bar which are directing to the pages under `user` folder throws exception as below:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.primefaces.renderkit.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:80)
org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeMenuItem(BaseMenuRenderer.java:148)
org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeElements(TieredMenuRenderer.java:103)
org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeSubmenu(TieredMenuRenderer.java:162)
org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeElements(TieredMenuRenderer.java:119)
org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMenu(TieredMenuRenderer.java:78)
org.primefaces.component.menubar.MenubarRenderer.encodeMarkup(MenubarRenderer.java:49)
org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:105)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

And the menu items under the template file(which is under `WEB-INF` directory) is like below:

```
<p:menuitem value="User Data" outcome="/user/userData" rendered="#{sessionBean.loggedIn}"/>

<p:menuitem icon="ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical" rendered="#{sessionBean.loggedIn}"/>

<p:submenu label="Yardım" >
    <p:menuitem value="About Us" outcome="about" icon="ui-icon-help" />
</p:submenu>
```

I can't access the `userData.xhtml`(and any other) under `user` folder and i get the exception above. i placed a plain html page under `user` folder and i can access it.

I tried so many things but couldn't find the problem.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I suppose it's mistyping, but you need enclosing brackets for first `menuitem` value. Having seen this error many times before, it just tells you one of your outcomes is not being found.

Comment: As @XtremeBiker said, you should enclose the double quote of the `value` attribute of the 1st `menuitem` tag, so that `outcome` and its successor attributes could be correctly identified.

Comment: Actually it's typo while asking the question, not on the code. I corrected it above. So the reason is something else. May it be because i use templating?

Answer (score 2):

change outcome tag with url=""

```
<p:menuitem value="About Us" url="about.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-help" />
```